# How to add a menu to an application without .xib or storyboard file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, menubar

My application does not have a working menu bar. There is just the applications name in the menu bar. Since I do not have the concerning window in my .xib file, I am not able to link it that way. Although the Menu is contained in the .xib file.

I tried many different solutions like:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] setMenu:mainMenu];
```

But they didn't work at all. No menu appears there's just the applications name as usual.

I would appreciate every possible help :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**if you have the Menu present in XIB but the your Menu class is not linked (can't see class values) then:**

Open xib file -> select the View Controller -> show Utilities Panel (right side menu) -> select Identity Inspector tab -> Edit "Class" to xxx

where xxx is the name of your class.

**If you don't use any storyboard nor a any xib file that contains the main App Window then:**

You have to add the UIWindow manually in AppDelegate.m->AppDidFinishLoading method.

Set you Root View Controller to that UIWindow:

```
[window setRootViewController:[self mainView]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: There isn't a method called setRootViewController :(